# Bank tell me it is safe to wait for real-estate loan offer

Tags: real-estate, france, banking

I'm trying to buy a real-estate and I have already signed a sales agreement.

The bank tells me it is slow currently to print an "Offre de prêt" (loan offer), and has given an "Accord de prêt" document (agreement to loan). This document is not enough to

This document is valid for one month and is dated a month ago from now. It also mention It also says that I should return the signed loan offer before next friday, but I don't have them yet.

Can the bank say tomorrow that their agreement has expired because I haven't signed the documents they didn't send to me?

The bank tells me they can't make any promise about when they will be able to print the loan offer, and I have to pay large compensation to the seller (tens of thousands euros) if I'm not able to give them the full payement in time.

What should I do regarding this document? Does it have any legal, enforcable value?